# Setting sensitivity to specific Gtk3 MenuActions (python)

Tags: python, gtk3

I have an app where some menu-actions are not supposed to be sensitive before some other things have happened (as in the minimal code below, 'Save' makes no sense before 'New' has been clicked).

It is simple to go about setting an entire menu, such as the File-menu in the example insensitive. It is also easy to set toolbar-buttons insensitive. Both of those appear as children to the `MenuBar` and the `ToolBar` respectively.

However, I'm completely lost when I try to set individual Actions of the Menus.
I simply don't find the path to them. Neither going up from the them (after they've been pressed) as in the `_do_save` method in the example, nor going from the menu down.

**Question:**

*How do I set a 'Save' insensitive from start and get it to become sensitive when 'New' has been clicked?*

**Requirement:**

I still want to use the `UIManager` as below to set up the menu.

The solution should not require the user to click 'Save' to toggle its sensitivity, it should be insensitive from start.

**Minimal Code:**

The comment in `__init__` show's where I hope to access the menu-action...

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from gi.repository import Gtk


class W(Gtk.Window):

    UI = """
    <menubar name="MainMenu">
        <menu action="MenuFile">
            <menuitem action="MenuNew" />
            <menuitem action="MenuSave" />
            <separator />
            <menuitem action="MenuQuit" />
        </menu>
    </menubar>
    """

    def __init__(self):

        super(W, self).__init__()
        self.set_default_size(300, 300)
        self.connect("destroy", Gtk.main_quit)

        box = Gtk.Box(orientation=Gtk.Orientation.VERTICAL)
        self.add(box)

        action_group = Gtk.ActionGroup("ui_actions")
        action_group.add_actions(
            [
                ('MenuFile', None, '_File'),
                ('MenuNew', Gtk.STOCK_NEW, '_New', None, 'Should enable save',
                 self._do_new),
                ('MenuSave', Gtk.STOCK_SAVE, '_Save', None,
                 'Only sensitive after new', self._do_save),
                ('MenuQuit', Gtk.STOCK_QUIT, '_Quit', None, 'Exits',
                 Gtk.main_quit)
            ]
        )

        uim = Gtk.UIManager()
        uim.add_ui_from_string(self.UI)
        self.add_accel_group(uim.get_accel_group())
        uim.insert_action_group(action_group)

        self._menu = uim.get_widget("/MainMenu")
        box.pack_start(self._menu, False, False, 0)

        #HERE'S WHERE I DON'T KNOW WHAT TO DO
        #How to append the widget corresponing ot 'MenuSave' into
        #self._sensitie_widgets
        self._sensitive_widgets = []
        self._set_sensitive_state(False)

        self.show_all()

    def _set_sensitive_state(self, val):
        """Does nothing now, because the GtkAction for 'MenuSave' has
        not been appended to self._set_sensitive_state"""

        for w in self._sensitive_widgets:
            w.set_sensitive(val)

    def _do_new(self, *args):
        """Callback should just invoke self._set_sensitive_state as below"""

        self._set_sensitive_state(True)

    def _do_save(self, widget):
        """This should only be possible after New has been pressed.
        Currently a failed attempt at tracing the way to access it."""
        def _do_trace(w):

            if hasattr(w, 'get_parent'):
                _do_trace(w.get_parent())

            else:
                print dir(w)
            print w

        _do_trace(widget)

if __name__ == "__main__":

    w = W()
    Gtk.main()
```

Any help would be much appreciated, because I'm loosing my head over this (it feels like it ought to be quite straight forward)...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
w = [uim.get_widget('/MainMenu/MenuFile/MenuSave')]
```

Comment: Wow, that was definitely easy!

Comment: Another solution: create and save Action objects:
`action_save = Gtk.Action('MenuSave', ...)`
`w = [action_save]`